# Encrypting password by date experiment

Tags: python, encoding, hash

I am working on my first real coding project and would like to create a tool to encode my login information for my personal VPN based on the date and possibly time. I'm doing this so that even if I log into my server with compromised wifi my server would still be safe.

```
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
today = str(today).replace('-', '')


import hashlib


imput = "password"
h = hashlib.sha256(imput.encode(today))


hash = h.hexdigest()
print(hash)
```

The error I get while working on this is:

```
h = hashlib.sha256(imput.encode(today))
LookupError: unknown encoding: 20201017
```

I know this is a very basic issue but I am just barely learning so any help getting this functional would be great.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You can increase the chance of getting an answer if you edit your question and additionally tag the programming language you are using because many experts see only "their" language. Regarding your problem: The output of your today variable seems to be a string that is not in the right format for your sha256-hash - one idea would be to search for e.g. "python sha256 eample".

Answer (score 0):

[str.encode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) accepts as encoding one of the available [standard encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings). You are passing the string `20201017` which results in the error message.

Instead you can pass any of the available encodings or simply none if you want to use the standard encoding `utf-8`.

```python
h = hashlib.sha256(imput.encode())
hash = h.hexdigest()
print(hash)
```

prints

```
5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8
```

If you don't like to use `utf-8` you can also convert the string into a [byte literal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6269785/2129801).

```python
h = hashlib.sha256(b"imput")
hash = h.hexdigest()
print(hash)
```

prints

```
c8437f4785336512556fea9d3f32c319e2674a610872a14fc33876aa116d7247
```

Comment: do you know how to convert a variable into a byte literal?

Comment: @SquishyKnight did you check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6269785/2129801)?